# Is rikulo autogenerated view.css mandatory?

Tags: dart, rikulo

Rikulo generates the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="packages/rikulo_ui/css/default/view.css" />
```

style sheet.

If I remove this and add a custom style sheet, everything changes. Is the autogenerated styles mandatory? If so, how should I now add my custom styles?

If I should put two styles sheet as shown below...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="epimss.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="packages/rikulo_ui/css/default/view.css" />
```

...which one is used or is both used?

I am asking because of the differed view appearance when I experiment with these possibilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a few rules in view.css are important. It is suggested to include it first and then include yours.

If you really don't want to include it, you have to specify the following in your CSS file:

```
.v- {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```